# How to programmaticaly print two copies of the same document in Active Reports?

Tags: designer, activereports, end-user

My customer wants an ActiveReports report to be printed twice as original and copy. Is it possible to do this programmatically or I need to create that report copy and include it as subreport?

Cheers,
Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the copies in code to 2 and your customer should get what he wants.
here is [a link](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/arHOWPrintMultipleCopiesDuplexLandscape.html)

Comment: Thank you! :)  ActiveReports is quite well documented, but I always have some difficulties with finding what I am looking for... :\